# Basic Typescript app issue with importing and exporting

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very basic Typescript app and Chrome is complaining about the following when opening my index.html page:

> exports is not defined
>
> import is not defined

*app.ts*

```
import Timer from "./models/timer";

class Startup {
    public static main() {
        // Initialize timer
        var timer = new Timer(new Date("25/12/2015 00:00:00"));
        // Start timer
        timer.start();
    }
}

Startup.main();
```

*models/timer.ts*

```
export default class Timer {
    target: Date;
    days: number;
    hours: number;
    minutes: number;
    seconds: number;
    constructor(target: Date) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    start() {
        var now = Date.now;
        alert(now);
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio code and have the following:

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

*tasks.json*

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the compiled.js file in your html code?

Comment: @PaulL yep. Reference both .js outputted files in my index.html

Comment: Can you run the js file inside node: `node app.js`

Answer (score 1):

from your errors :

```
exports is not defined

import is not defined
```

You need a module loader! Browsers don't natively understand modules yet. Recommend using `webpack` (other options include browserify etc.).

## More

Quickstart: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html